# struggling with python homework

Tags: python

I got a .txt file with some lines in it:

```
325255, Jan Jansen      
334343, Erik Materus   
235434, Ali Ahson  
645345, Eva Versteeg  
534545, Jan de Wilde  
345355, Henk de Vries
```

1. Write a program that starts with opening the file kaartnummers.txt
2. Determine the number of lines and the largest card number in the file. Then print these data.

my code isnt finished yet but i tried atleast!:

```
def kaartinfo():
    lst = []
    infile = open('kaartnummers.txt', 'r')
    content = infile.readlines()

    print(len(content))
    for i in content:
        print(i.split())
kaartinfo()
```

I know that my program opens the file and counts the number of lines in it.. all after that is wrong <3

I can't figure out how to get the max number in the list.. Please if you got an answer use simple readable Python Language.

Comment: Have you looked at the `max()` function? That said, nobody is likely to answer this as you are looking for work to be done, not help with a specific problem.

Comment: Please write the question structured and without useless information and rant.

Comment: This is not a specific question but a request for people to do your work for you. That is not acceptable here. Please keep trying until you run into a *specific* issue that you don't understand, then come back and ask.

Comment: Your first step would be to not only *count*, but actually *read* the content. For this, you already prepared the empty `lst`. Once you find your content, you can use the `max` function (that should be the easiest part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not good at python, and there are probably much more elegant solutions, but this is how I would do it. Some may say this is like C++/Java in python, which many tend to avoid.

```
def kaartinfo():
    lst = []
    infile = open('kaartnummers.txt', 'r')
    content = infile.readlines()

    for i in content:
        value = i.split(',')
        value[0] = int(value[0])
        lst.append(value)

    return lst
```

## Use the kaartinfo() function to retrieve a list

```
my_list = kaartinfo()
```

## Assume first value is the maximum

```
maximumValue = my_list[0][0]
```

## Go through every value in the list, check if they are greater than the current maximum

```
# if they are, set them as the new current maximum
for ele in my_list:
    if ele[0] > maximumValue:
        maximumValue = ele[0]
```

## when the above loop finishes, maximum value will be the largest value in the list.

```
#Convert the integer back to a string, and print the result
print(str(maximumValue) + ' is the maximum value in the file!')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough to do the job:

```
with open('kaartnummers.txt', 'r') as f:

    data = f.readlines()

    print('There are %d lines in the file.' % len(data))
    print('Max value is %s.' % max(line.split(',')[0] for line in data))
```

Given the input file you provided, the output would be:

> There are 6 lines in the file.
>
> Max value is 645345.

Of course, you can put it in a function if you like.